# Avada section, just will not delete?

Tags: wordpress, image, sections

This may seem pretty basic, but i have tried everything I know, to get rid of this image, but it will not go. It's not even on the website anymore and it still appears!

I need this whole section to go and it's so annoying.

Here is the page: http://preview.geomedia.co.uk/nursteadcourt/our-destination/nurstead-court-one/

So all I need it to delete this: http://prntscr.com/i5yve2

If any one has any ideas please do let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Elliot.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. I'll give you the simplest answer.

Usually the header is saved as a featured image.  In which case you can change it to whatever you want. If the template was built well, you should be able to remove it and that should work.

If not, try going into Appearance/Editor and at the bottom of the file add this CSS.

```
.fusion-page-title-bar { display: none; }
```

This will hide the header.

Comment: Ah brilliant, that has done the trick, I typed in something similar and it didn't do anything!  Is there any way to change 2 more things: http://prntscr.com/i5z8do

Comment: I need to change the word related to gallery. Then just hide the post dates for the images

Comment: Sure! Just add this CSS to the Editor.

.fusion-date, .fusion-inline-sep { display: none;}

Changing the word is going to be much more difficult.

Comment: Do me a favor and give me an upvote if I was helpful :)

Comment: Thank you John, I believe I have up voted you now! I will make another post for the change of the wording.